# ¿Cómo posicionar una imagen centrada dentro de una ventana con grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy comenzando a aprender sobre Python y estoy en el momento aprendiendo el uso del modulo Tkinter.  Estoy haciendo un formulario cualquiera donde estoy capturando 3 datos y abajo intento poner una imagen en un label (`lblLogo`), pero **no logro centrarla bien, no me queda bien ubicada**.

Estoy usando `grid()` pero no hallo como ubicar bien dicha imagen, quiero centrarla abajo lo mejor que pueda. Al momento de ejecutar el logo casi se desaparece a la derecha de la ventana.

El siguiente es el código que estoy usando:

```
# Se importa la libreria
import tkinter

# De la libreria importar todo
from tkinter import *

# Creamos la ventana
root = tkinter.Tk()

# Titulo y tamaño a la ventana
root.title("Manejo de Etiquetas, Ventanas e Imagenes")
root.geometry("500x400")

# Evitar modificar tamaño de la ventana
root.resizable(0,0) 

#creamos ventana o frame principal
vp = Frame(root)

#configuramos el grid
vp.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(20,20), pady=(10,10))
vp.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
vp.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

# creamos los campos
etiqueta1 = Label(vp, text="Nombre: ")
etiqueta1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada1 = Entry(vp, width=50)
entrada1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5)

etiqueta2 = Label(vp, text="Ciudad: ")
etiqueta2.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada2 = Entry(vp, width=50)
entrada2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5)

etiqueta3 = Label(vp, text="Contraseña: ")
etiqueta3.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada3 = Entry(vp, width=25)
entrada3.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5, sticky="w")
entrada3.config(justify="left", show="*")

# Cargar imagen y modifico tamaño
img = PhotoImage(file="python-logo.png")
img = img.subsample(2,2)

# Creo el label para el logo o imagen
lblLogo = Label(root, image=img,relief = RAISED)

# Coloco el Logo en la Ventana Principal
#lblLogo.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
lblLogo.grid(row=9, column=1)

# Finalmente el bucle de la aplicación
root.mainloop()
```

---

Asi tengo el codigo ahora:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Creamos la ventana
root = tk.Tk()

# Titulo y tamaño a la ventana
root.title("Manejo de Etiquetas, Ventanas e Imagenes")
root.geometry("500x400")

# Evitar modificar tamaño de la ventana
root.resizable(0,0) 

#vp -> ventana o frame principal
vp = Frame(root)

vp.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(20,20), pady=(10,10))
vp.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
vp.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

etiqueta1 = Label(vp, text="Nombre: ")
etiqueta1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada1 = Entry(vp, width=50)
#entrada1 = Entry(vp)
entrada1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
#entrada1.grid_propagate(flag=True)

etiqueta2 = Label(vp, text="Ciudad: ")
etiqueta2.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada2 = Entry(vp, width=50)
entrada2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5)

etiqueta3 = Label(vp, text="Contraseña: ")
etiqueta3.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada3 = Entry(vp, width=25)
entrada3.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5, sticky="w")
entrada3.config(justify="left", show="*")

#Cargar imagen y modifico tamaño
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="python-logo.png")
img = img.subsample(2, 2)

#Creo el label para el logo o imagen
lblLogo = tk.Label(vp, image=img)  # <<<<<<<< Ahora el padre es vp, no root
lblLogo.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(10, 10))

# Finalmente bucle de la aplicación
root.mainloop()
```

---

Ok amigo, ya veo, gracias.

Por que en este trozo de codigo, usted antepone tk al Label, mas no al grid?

```
#Creo el label para el logo o imagen
lblLogo = tk.Label(vp, image=img)  # <<<<<<<< Ahora el padre es vp, no root
lblLogo.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(10, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que posicionas el `Label` en `root`, no en el `Frame` `vp`. Es decir, el `Label` con la imagen es hermano de `vp`, no hijo. Es importante porque el administrador de geometría `grid` del `Frame` y el de `root` son independientes, son widgets distintos. Tu ventana principal tiene una columna y una fila dónde posicionas el `Frame`, el `Label` con la imagen debería ir en la fila 1 y columna 0, debajo del `Frame` (fila 0, columna 0):

```
# Se importa la libreria
import tkinter as tk


# Creamos la ventana
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Mi formulario")

# Evitar modificar tamaño de la ventana
root.resizable(0, 0) 

# Creamos frame principal
vp = tk.Frame(root)

# Posicionamos frame en ventana principal
vp.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(20, 20), pady=(10, 10))

# Creamos los campos
etiqueta1 = tk.Label(vp, text="Nombre: ")
etiqueta1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada1 = tk.Entry(vp, width=50)
entrada1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5)

etiqueta2 = tk.Label(vp, text="Ciudad: ")
etiqueta2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada2 = tk.Entry(vp, width=50)
entrada2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5)

etiqueta3 = tk.Label(vp, text="Contraseña: ")
etiqueta3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=10)
entrada3 = tk.Entry(vp, width=25)
entrada3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=5, sticky="w")
entrada3.config(justify="left", show="*")

# Cargar imagen y modifico tamaño
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="python-logo.png")
img = img.subsample(2, 2)

# Creo el label para el logo o imagen
lblLogo = tk.Label(root, image=img)
lblLogo.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(10, 10))

# Finalmente el bucle de la aplicación
root.mainloop()
```

Si quieres posicionar el logo dentro del `Frame`, simplemente debes usar la fila debajo de la última pareja de `Label-Entry` y usar el argumento `columnspan` para que ocupe dos columnas (que son las que usan los labels y entries anteriores) para que quede centrado:

```
# Cargar imagen y modifico tamaño
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="python-logo.png")
img = img.subsample(2, 2)

# Creo el label para el logo o imagen
lblLogo = tk.Label(vp, image=img)  # <<<<<<<< Ahora el padre es vp, no root
lblLogo.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(10, 10))
```

Usas dos formas distintas de importar, la segunda con `*` (star/wildcard) es considerada generalmente una mala práctica y debe evitarse. La primera es correcta, pero para evitar referenciar a `tkinter` cada vez se suele usar un alias, la forma que por convención se usa es `import tkinter as tk`.

El resultado en cualquier caso es algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo, eso era lo que necesitaba. Acertada explicacion.

Comment: Amigo, ya traté de hacer los cambios que me indicó pero me sale este error, usted perdone, soy novato. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry2.py", line 14, in <module>
    vp = Frame(root)
NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined

***Repl Closed***

Comment: Si cambias el import a `import tkinter as tk`, debes anteponer el namespace `tk` para referenciar las clases o constantes definidas en tkinter, si te fijas en mi ejemplo es:  `vp = tk.Frame(root)`, no  `vp = Frame(root)`. Puede parecer que es escribir más porque sí, pero hay muy buenas razones para ello, la primera la legibilidad al saber de dónde viene cada nombre (y la legibilidad importa mucho en el entorno Python) y otra es que importar con * conlleva que no sepamos que estamos importando y es fácil solapar namespaces lo que ocasionan a veces errores muy difíciles de depurar.

Comment: Puede parecer una tontería en proyectos pequeños (y aun así aquí hay preguntas con errores causados por ésta práctica), pero en proyectos grandes puede llegar a ser una pesadilla. Importar con * tiene su utilidad en algunos casos muy concretos siempre que sepamos que estamos haciendo al 100%, pero nunca debe usarse para ahorrarse el escribir tres o cuatro caracteres... Es una práctica similar al `#using namespace std` de C++...